# Bayesian estimator not converging

Tags: bayesian, estimation, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution

I am trying to run a simple experiment using python.

I have a binomial distribution (n = 100, p = 0.6).
I am trying to estimate the proportion p of this binom distribution using a Beta(1, 1) as a prior.

I am observing 100,000 samples (For each sample, I am running 20 Bernoulli trials, with p = 0.6 and summing up the values as k, using numpy's inbuilt function).

The posterior value of p is then simply (a + k) /(a + b + 20).

I expect these values to converge very closely to 0.6, but they seem to be erratic.
For smaller number of trails, sometimes the values are more closer to 0.6.

```
10000 0.5988901109889011
20000 0.5993450327483626
30000 0.5998716709443018
40000 0.6003287417814555
50000 0.6006119877602448
60000 0.600478325361244
70000 0.6005364209082728
80000 0.6003837452031849
90000 0.6004372173642515
```

I am interested to know if there is any finite number of trials, which will give the closest approximation, or what is the rule to determine the optimum number of trials.

Comment: Could you more specifically describe what you see as being "erratic" in these values?  They look like they are converging to the expected value of $0.6.$

Comment: Hi Whuber, For 40000 samples ( size 20 each) , we have  0.6003287417814555 , but at 90000 samples it is farther at 0.6004372173642515. I was hoping for each successive sample to get closer & closer to 0.6.

Comment: Your results are random, so they will vary randomly.  You had some unlucky draws between steps 80000 and 90000.  You can confirm this by plotting all data or simply by repeating the exercise with different random numbers.